# PHP Redis (yii2-redis) set expiry time with MSET command

Tags: php, caching, redis, yii

I'm able to set the expiry on a key with the `SET` command as follows:

`redis->executeCommand('SET',['key','value','EX',10000]);`

I'm trying to use the `MSET` command instead to set multiple values at once. I can accomplish this as follows:

`redis->executeCommand('MSET', ['key','value','key2','value2','key3','value3']);`

I'm not sure how to set the expiry on the above keys though. I'd like to apply the same expiry time to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't yii2-Redis specific, but rather a constraint/limitation of Redis itself. The `MSET` command does not provide a way to set TTLs - either use `SET...EX` for each key, or call `EXPIRE` for each key set by `MSET`.

Comment: ah okay - what do you think the most efficient way of doing this would be? The reason I'm using MSET is because I want to minimise the number of network calls to redis - as far as I'm aware yii2 redis doesn't support pipelining, which is why I'm not setting each key individually within a pipeline

Comment: "minimise the number of network calls" <- good consideration. In lieu of pipelining, have you considered using a Lua script (https://redis.io/commands/eval)?